# what could be the reason for the importerror

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to train a model of CNN. 
When I run the code, it returns following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_network.py", line 5, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "/home/kaustubhj/.virtualenvs/dl4cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "/home/kaustubhj/.virtualenvs/dl4cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/kaustubhj/.virtualenvs/dl4cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/kaustubhj/.virtualenvs/dl4cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
    from . import _dtype_ctypes
  File "/home/kaustubhj/.virtualenvs/dl4cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_dtype_ctypes.py", line 25, in <module>
    import _ctypes
ImportError: libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What OS are you running?

Answer (score 1):

**ImportError** generally refers to an import library required for execution is not present within executing systems.

Few possible cases to look for.

1. In a general case, your system where py is running is missing this package.
2. In Spark(general-purpose computing cluster), if you are running this cnn then one of your worker node could be missing file/package.
3. Bugs: In Py bug tracker this bug reported for some package like `Pipenv`. This resolved as per https://bugs.python.org/issue40367 Just upgrade your used libs to stable version
4. If its path issue then check for which python you have installed library and which version you are using. I.e. there could be multiple python version in your systems. Python2 pkgs repo and Python3 pkgs repo loc are different.
5. If its simple OS path issue - https://jackiechen.org/2016/01/13/importerror-libffi-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory/

Try to just use the latest version or switch to more stable version packages to avoid this error.